# Mysql group_concat for count in sub query using parent filed is not allowed

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to process album count for each of the country per artist; however, I have a problem once I do group_concat for count in mysql, I search a bit in stackoverflow, I found I have to do sub select for group_concat. The problem is once I do the sub select in from I can not use a.id from the parent from filed table. I got error  like following  Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause'

This is the query:

```
 SELECT a.seq_id, a.id
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) AS cnt FROM (
   SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', mgr.country_code, count(mgr.media_id)) AS cnt
    FROM music_album_artists AS ma
    JOIN media_geo_restrict AS mgr ON ma.album_id = mgr.media_id
    WHERE ma.artist_id = a.id
    GROUP BY mgr.country_code
  ) count_table
 ) AS album_count
FROM music_artist AS a 
WHERE a.seq_id > 0 and a.seq_id < 10000
```

The sample data in tables:

```
music_artists:
seq_id   id     name
1        1      Hola
2        2      Vivi

music_album_artists:
id     artist_id    album_id
1      1            1
2      1            2
3      1            5
4      1            10
5      2            2
6      2            10
6      2            1

media_geo_restrict:
album_id     country_code
1            BE
1            CA
1            DE
1            US
2            CH
2            CA
2            CH
5            DE
10           US
```

The result I would like to have

```
seq_id    id    album_count 
1         1     BE--1,CA--2,CH--1,DE--1,US--1
2         2     CA--1,US--2,CH--1
```

Comment: t would be great if you could show us a small sample of your data and from it what would be the result you want. It would be easier to help you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I added the sample of result in question

Comment: Added an answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
select seq_id, id, group_concat(concat(country_code, '--', qtd))
from (
select ma.seq_id, ma.id,
       mgr.country_code, count(*) qtd
from music_artists ma
     inner join music_album_artists maa
           on ma.id = maa.artist_id
     inner join media_geo_restrict mgr
           on maa.album_id = mgr.album_id
where ma.seq_id > 0 and ma.seq_id < 10000
group by ma.seq_id, ma.id, ma.name,
       mgr.country_code
) tb
group by seq_id, id
```

Here is the working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff8b5/8

Comment: Hi Jorge, I tried your query it works but it seems the query scan full table of music_artists, therefore, if I am running this query in the table of 20  million in batch of 20000 it is really slow. Do you think if it is possible to optimize it only take the seq_id range in sub table?

Comment: Just move the seq_id filter to the subquery. I will edit it. That info was not in the question so I did the obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tell me:

```
SELECT a.seq_id, a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) AS cnt
FROM music_artist AS a,
(
   SELECT ma.artist_id, CONCAT_WS('-', mgr.country_code, count(mgr.media_id)) AS cnt
    FROM music_album_artists AS ma
    JOIN media_geo_restrict AS mgr ON ma.album_id = mgr.album_id
    GROUP BY mgr.country_code
  ) AS count_table
WHERE a.seq_id > 0 and a.seq_id < 10000
and a.id=count_table.artist_id
group by a.id
```

Comment: Need some fixes: There is no `music_artist` table and there is no `media_id` column.